# Why downloaded file size is different from original file in server?

Tags: java, servlets, file-io

I have a file in server. A.xls.
The client wants it to be encrypted. So i did.
The new file name is B.xls.
When i downloaded B.xls using HttpServletResponse stream, the result made me confused.
Because the downloaded file size was different from the B.xls.

A.xls size is 3kb.
B.xls size is 6kb.
But the downloaded file size is 5kb.

Please give me a tip to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////
///// this is my code. ////////////////////

File file = new File(tempDir+filename);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( file );  
byte[] readBuff = new byte[4096];
int readLen = -1;           
try {  
    while( ( readLen = is.read( readBuff ) ) != -1 ) {
      fos.write( readBuff, 0, readLen );
    }
    fos.flush();
} finally {
    if( fos != null ) {
        try {fos.close();} catch( IOException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }                       
}

//## Encrypt the target File ##
// Do - Something
// the new file name is enc_filename

outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
File encFile = new File(tempDir+enc_filename);
System.out.println("enc file size :" + encFile.length());
outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
inputStream = new FileInputStream( encFile );
readLen = -1;
while( ( readLen = inputStream.read() ) != -1 ) {
    outputStream.write(readLen);
}
outputStream.flush();
......
close stream code....
......
```

Comment: How are you measuring the size of the downloaded file?

Comment: where your Servlet is running, OS?

Comment: @Maxim What difference would that make exactly?

Comment: because on Linux and windows the same file has different size

Comment: @MaximShoustin 1k different?

Comment: @EJP Could very well be the case depending on the file system used.  If one uses block sizes of 4k then the size may vary by that.

Comment: @aspirant75 Try calculating a checksum (like MD5 or SHA1) for the file on client and server.  If they are equal you can ignore the difference in size since the cause then would be just a imprecision in measuring.

Comment: [Stewart] I measured the size of the downloaded file using File Object. like File f = new File("downloaded file"); f.length();

Comment: [EJP] Yes, there is just 1k difference.  It makes not to decrpyt the downloaded file.

Comment: [Viktor Seifert] I test it on my local tomcat server. the tomcat server runs on Window 7. I will try to calculate checksum for the file later. I am going to leave the office for serveral days. When i check the checksum, i let you know the result.

Comment: [Viktor Seifert] I checked the file's checksum. As expected, the output was different. What do i do to solve this problem?

Comment: In addition, i printed the read data one byte by one. The encrypted file printed 6126 bytes and downloaded file printed 5120 bytes. the both stream print the same data til 5120 bytes. Why response.getOutputStream() didn't write the rest 1006 bytes?

Comment: I solved this problem by adding response.setContentLength(inputStream.available()); Thanks all.